# Is there any way to make autocompletion work for command option names in Bash?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I'm using Bash 4.4.

```
[root@192 ~]# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
[root@192 ~]#
```

I would like to know if there is any way to make autocompletion work for option names. For example, if I type `realpath --re` and followed by a <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it helps me to fill out the missing part of the option name and I got `realpath --relative-to=`.

Comment: Do you have [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) installed? What's your distro? The short answer is yes, but it pretty much has to be configured on a per-command basis, but packages like that cover a bunch of them.

Comment: @frabjous Yes I have bash-completion enabled. I'm on RHEL 8.3. Are you saying that this can be done using that bash-completion? I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have bash-completion enabled, then the command options are already there for the completion of the commands. You can see a lot of scripts and functions used for that purpose somewhere like `/usr/share/bash-completion`.
Installed packages like `git` put their scripts into `/etc/bash_completion.d/`.

Still there could be some scripts, like `realpath` or `echo`, with limited completion. To add completion for the long options for `realpath` you should use `_longopt`, which is a bash function for generating completion, you can see it with `type -a`.

```
complete -F _longopt realpath
```

Before doing this, you have  to test if there is already a completion for what you try to change, with:

```
complete -p realpath
```

which could say `no completion specification` or an existing rule, like `complete -F _minimal realpath`. The new rule would overwrite it. So you shouldn't blindly assign any function, existing or custom, to a lot of commands. The completion rules are already there for the commands.

The change is available for your current shell. To make it permanent, you have to `source` it, e.g. via `bashrc`.